# Gearman commands and service don't work the same

Tags: perl, gearman

I ran into a strange problem when testing my gearman settings. Since I have only one PC and would like to test gearman cross-platform features, I installed gearman job server on Ubuntu 12.04 on the virtual box on a Win7 system and launch the worker on Win7. The virtualbox and host machine ping each other smoothly. Here's my worker's code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Gearman::Worker;

my $worker1 = Gearman::Worker->new;
$worker1->job_servers('10.38.50.158');

# register job
$worker1->register_function( print_task1 => \&print_task1 ); 

$worker1->work while 1; 

sub print_task1{
    my ($job) = @_;
    print "Worker1 starts...\n";
    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)=localtime(time);
    printf("%d:%d:%d\n",$hour,$min,$sec);
    sleep 10;
    $job->set_status(50,100);
    sleep 10;
    $job->set_status(100,100);
}
```

And `PARAMS` in `/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server` of job server on Ubuntu is `--listen=127.0.0.1 --port=7003`.

When I launch the gearman server on Ubuntu with `gearmand -d -p 7003`, the worker could register on the job server, I confirmed it by checking the server status. However, when I launch the gearman server by `sudo service gearman-job-service start`, the worker failed to register.

Could you give some hints about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--listen` indicates the address the server must listen to. If you use `--listen=127.0.0.1`, the server will only catch worker registration of localhost. The default value is `INADDR_ANY` which means the server will listen to any machines if you leave this option empty.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the reason: the `PARAMS` in `/etc/init.d/gearman-job-server` of job server should be only `--port=7003`, without `--listen=127.0.0.1`! I don't know what's the problem here, I just tried it out. I'm still learning about gearman, but I'm sure I made a quite stupid mistake earlier.